# C allocating char array causing bad access runtime exception

Tags: c, memory-management, runtime

I seem to be having trouble correctly allocating memory for my array. The method is returning as expected, but a runtime exception is killing the program.

I got this exception while using my debugger.

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
```

This is the method causing the issue:

```
char *progScanner(char *line){

    char originalLine[100];
    strcpy(originalLine, line);
    char *correctLine[100];
    char *segment;
    int i = 0;

    segment = strtok(originalLine," ,()");
    while (segment != NULL){
        printf (" %s",segment);
        correctLine[i++] = segment;
        segment = strtok (NULL, " ,()");
    }

    char *newLine;
    newLine = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
    int j = 1;
    strcpy (newLine, correctLine[0]);
    while(j<=i){
        strcat(newLine, correctLine[j]);
        j++;
    }

    return newLine;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the original line is less than 100 characters long? If it's longer, you'll cause undefined behavior.

Comment: The error indicates that you're trying to dereference a null pointer. Step through the code with a debugger to see where this is happening.

Comment: `while(j<=i)` should be `while(j<i)`.

Comment: Unrelated, but the use of `strcat` in a loop like this is a textbook case of Schlemiel The Painter. https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: @Barmar you're right, please leave an answer. Can't believe I missed that for so long.

Comment: I believe you need to allocate  dynamic memory instead of using  "char originalLine[100];" because if you exceed the 100 you will face with exception.

Comment: Using strdup to get dynamically allocated strings would be safer than using strcpy without checking the size of the input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing outside the `correctLine` array when you get to `j == i`, because the last valid index in `correctLine` is `j-1`. Change

```
while(j<=i){
```

to

```
while(j<i){
```